# How do you get the regular software center from Ubuntu on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, mate

I am a relatively new Linux user and I use Ubuntu MATE. I cannot figure out how to get the regular Ubuntu Software Center on my computer. I cannot even find the software center they have provided with the OS. Is there a better software center for Ubuntu MATE, and if how can you get it?

Answer (score 5):

Use command `sudo apt-get install software-center` to install the software center.

Also, there should be a GUI with a "software" button in a welcome screen at login (if not,  Applications -> System -> Ubuntu MATE Welcome), from which you can choose a software manager.

[image]

Comment: when I run `sudo apt-get install software-center`, I get `Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source` follower by `E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @HelloGoodbye it appears that software-center is not found in your software repositories, are you perchance running an older, no longer supported version of ubuntu? If so, first upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: I'm running the newest Ubuntu MATE LTS, i.e. 18.04

Comment: What software repositories _should_ I have? Which one do you have `software-center` in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ubuntu MATE, but I think it now comes with a *"Software Boutique"*, instead of a *"Software Center"*. Big deal.

But you can always use `apt` from the command line:

```
apt-cache search software-center
sudo apt install software-center
```

And if that does the job, then you don't need the software-center!

Comment: Does not work.  Says there is no installation canidate

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Mate 22.04:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```